# React Native Keychain - Cannot read property 'getSupportedBiometryType' of null

Tags: react-native, android-biometric-prompt, android-biometric, react-native-keychain

I have followed the installation steps, but when I start the application on android I get an error saying: "Cannot read property 'getSupportedBiometryType' of null, please check the last image.

1. Run yarn add react-native-keychain - Only for React Native <= 0.59: $ react-native link react-native-keychain and check MainApplication.java to verify the package was added. See manual installation below if you have issues with the react-native link.
2. Run pod install in iOS/directory to install iOS dependencies.
3. If you want to support FaceID, add an NSFaceIDUsageDescription entry in your Info.plist.
   Re-build your Android and iOS projects.`
   On iOS Everything works fine and the getSupportedBiometryType returns a string or null depending if the biometrics authentication is enabled.
   On android on another hand, I get a Render Error: Cannot Read property 'getSupportedBiometryType' of null.
4. I also did the react-native link react-native-keychain command to try to fix the issue, but I had no luck.

Note: I also did the Manual Android install as described in the library installation guide.

Note: Everything works fine on iOS.

Packages:

"react-native": "0.64.2"
"react-native-keychain": "^8.1.0"

[Keychain library import](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ah4Bj.png)

[.getSupportedBiometryType() function call](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LjdEW.png)

[Error Message on Android Device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FNn2w.png)